# Removing a duplicate Python installation on RHEL

Tags: yum

I have a RHEL box with two installations of Python, how do I specify which to remove? I've tried "package-cleanup --cleandupes" but it's had no effect.

Here's the dupes:

```
[root@lolserver:~/]# rpm -qa python
python-2.7.5-79.el7_6.x86_64
python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64
```

```
[root@lolserver:~/]# yum --showduplicates list python | expand
Installed Packages
python.x86_64                2.7.5-79.el7_6                  @rhel7
python.x86_64                2.7.5-86.el7                    installed
```

I'd like to remove python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64 which was manually installed via an RPM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do rpm -e.

Something like:

> $ sudo rpm -e python-2.7.5-86.el7.x86_64